# How to solve this definite integral $\int_0^1{\frac{at+b}{\sqrt{ct^2+dt+f}}\arctan(\frac{gt+h}{\sqrt{ct^2+dt+f}})dt}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I'm trying to analytically integrate the following to get a closed form expression if possible. I have tried integrating by parts and it was getting pretty hairy. MATLAB symbolic toolkit was no help with this either. If anyone has good suggestions please contribute.

$$\int_0^1{\frac{at+b}{\sqrt{ct^2+dt+f}}\arctan(\frac{gt+h}{\sqrt{ct^2+dt+f}})dt}$$

$a$ through $h$ are real-valued constants.

Comment: what do we know about the variables?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, "$a$ to $h$ are constants".

Comment: If I recall my calculus classes the Hermite root theorem may help here.

Comment: @mathreadler The internet doesn't seem to know much about "Hermite root theorem". Does it go by any other names?

Comment: Yes you are right. It's not a theorem but an *ansatz* http://www.thphys.uni-heidelberg.de/~hefft/vk1/#755e

Comment: If $~at+b=k(2ct+d),~$ we have the following [result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/es4tk.png).

Comment: @Lucian what software did you use for that? Thanks.

Comment: @PowersofTwo: I use *Mathematica* and *Maple*.

Comment: So can this integral not be solved analytically?

Comment: Do you really need the case of absolutely general constants $a \to h$? Maybe you need some special case after all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we get rid of two unnecessary parameters, and rename the rest ($a,b,c,f,h$):

$$I=\int_0^1{\frac{t+a}{\sqrt{t^2+bt+c}}\arctan \left( f\frac{t+h}{\sqrt{t^2+bt+c}} \right) dt}$$

This integral is the same as in the OP up to a constant factor.

Now we use the celebrated [Euler substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution):

$$u=\sqrt{t^2+bt+c}-t$$

$$t=\frac{u^2-c}{b-2u}$$

---

After some elementary algebra we obtain:

$$dt=-2 \frac{u^2-bu+c}{(b-2u)^2}du$$

$$\frac{t+a}{\sqrt{t^2+bt+c}}=- \frac{u^2-2au+ab-c}{u^2-bu+c}$$

And finally:

> $$I=-2 \int_{\sqrt{c}}^{\sqrt{b+c+1}-1} \frac{u^2-2au+ab-c}{(b-2u)^2} \arctan \left(f \frac{u^2-2hu+hb-c}{u^2-bu+c} \right)du$$
>
> Now we have an integral of $\arctan$ of a rational argument multiplied by a rational function, which, using integration by parts, reduces to an integral of just a rational function, which always evaluates in elementary functions.

Thus, I consider the problem solved, unless the values of the parameters are specified.

Set:

$$P(u)=\frac{u^2-2au+ab-c}{(b-2u)^2}$$

$$Q(u)=f \frac{u^2-2hu+hb-c}{u^2-bu+c}$$

$$\int P(u) \arctan Q(u) du=\arctan Q(u) \int P(u) du-\int  \frac{Q'(u)}{1+Q^2(u)} \left(\int_\alpha^u P(v)dv \right) du$$

Here $\left(\int_\alpha^u P(v)dv \right)$ denotes a primitive of $P(u)$ (with $\alpha$ being some constant), defined according to the usual rules of integration by parts.

Comment: I have just seen this answer from Aug 19. Thank you very much for investing time in this question. I am going to have a look through now in more detail :)

Comment: This is really helpful, thank you! The Euler subsitution was the key step.